# Клиент (php на компе)- сервер (ANDROID)

Tags: php, java, android, веб-программирование, port

Здравствуйте. Кто знает,как открыть 80 порт? а то я не могу отправить запрос с android на php. Сканровал открыте порты - 80 там не оказалось. Отключал брендамуер windows , создавал правило для порта 80 - ничего не помогло. СОединял комп и телефон 1)через роутер еще пробывал 2) разадвал wifi с компа через connectify hotspot - и 80 порт везде закрыт. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста чем слушаете запросы на компьютере? Каким сервером и как он настроен?

Comment: @cheops Open Server. Отправляю запрос http с клиента и на сервере стоит для http 80 порт